# Date Fill filtering out fridays and holidays, and including Saturday and Sunday

Tags: excel, excel-formula, wps

[image]

I am trying to fill in the dates horizontally, Below are the criteria for the dates.

1. Not Including Holidays
2. Saturday and Sunday should be included
3. Friday is a holiday therefore should not be included

Below is the formula I entered,
`=IF(OR(WEEKDAY(S$3)=6,COUNTIF('Holidays '!$A$2:$A$9,S$3)),"",S$3)`

When i drag them, it shows the same date. What is the mistake I am doing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*If I have understood correctly from the OP then the following formula should work using `WORKDAY.INTL()` function:*

Here are the conditions which are followed:

- `Holidays` are not included. (Based on this [Georgian Calendar](https://www.timeanddate.com/calendar/?year=2024&country=35))
- `Saturday` and `Sundays` are included.
- `Fridays` are `holidays` hence should not be included.

---

[image]

---

• Formula used in cell <kbd>C3</kbd>

```
=WORKDAY.INTL(B3,1,16,Holidays[[Date]:[Date]])
```

---

The above formula needs to fill right, `16` means `Friday is weekend day`. In the above screenshot shown for two months i.e. from `February'24` to `March'24` and this should work for the rest of the months or years.

From the above screenshot, you can see that the `Fridays` are excluded, while `Saturdays` and `Sundays` are included, as well as the `Holidays` for the month of `Feb` say for example:

- 2/14/2024 - Day is `Wednesday` but `Holiday` as well hence not included.
- 2/19/2024 - Day is `Monday` but `Holiday` as well hence not included.
- 2/24/2024 - Day is `Saturday` but `Holiday` as well hence not included.

Likewise for the month of `March'24` for the example shown and will be working for the rest of the months in the year.

---

Holidays List for the `Feb'24` and `March'24` Months used as sample:

[image]

---

Answer (score 1):

If all you need to know is "why is it always producing the same date?", check your IF clause:

IF(condition, on true, on false)

Your question has cell T3 highlighted ... and the 'on not-a-holiday' value is "take the value from the previous column and put it here." At least you need to change this value.

I'm a bit fuzzy on how your COUNTIF() does the holiday check. Assuming that test is correct, however, I think you want T3 to contain:

```
IF(OR(your existing code here), S$3+2, S$3+1)
```

Answer (score 1):

I think your formula is actually correct.

Except that, you should write your formula in Row4, not in Row3.
While in range S3:AM3, you should input all dates.
e.g. you can try write below in cell S3:

```
=SEQUENCE(1,20,DATE(2024,2,1),1)
```

Then drag your own formula from S4 to AM4, like below:

[image: dates]